# How to stop list recycling On Scroll of list View, in a custom cursor adapter android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I  am creating one List divided by categories for that i am passing a view in list view (using Simple cursor adapter) using View Holder. So in my Custom simple cursor adapter I can set the visibility of one single bar on each items of the list. **But on scroll the visibility of that bar is not fixed for list items, it gets changed randomly up and down.** Check the code I am posting here.

When i call my custom Cursor list adapter's constructor from a normal activity then only i am passing all parameters(the view, cursor) , and *I am over riding only bind view* not newview.

please help me on this.

activity is:

```
 catCount = cursorCat.getCount();
int i=0;
cursorCat.moveToFirst();
do {
categ  =  cursorCat.getString(cursorCat.getColumnIndex("category_Name")); 
cursorCatItems = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, product_code, product_name, product_category, in_stock, price FROM ProductDetails WHERE _id || ' ' || product_name || product_code LIKE ? ",
new String[] { "%" +searchValue+ "%"});

adapter = new MforceAdapterCat(this, R.layout.item_details,
cursorCatItems, new String[] { "product_code", "product_name","product_category","in_stock","price" }, new int[] {
R.id.tvCode, R.id.tvItemName,R.id.tvItemType,R.id.tvQuantity,R.id.tvPrice });

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

i++;
} while (cursorCat.moveToNext() && i<catCount-1);              

cursorCat.close();

// down here is the code for list view items

      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
      public class MforceAdapterCat extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
        String prevCat="";
    int count=0;
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    protected ListAdapter adapter;

    public MforceAdapterCat(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public MforceAdapterCat(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}


   @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCode);
            holder.tvItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
            holder.tvItemType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemType);
            holder.tvPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            holder.tvQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
            holder.imgBtnLv=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnLv);
            holder.categBar=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.categBar);
            holder.tvTitleCateg=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleCateg);

            holder.item_detail_layout=(RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_detail_layout);


            String currCategory =   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_category"));

         holder.tvTitleCateg.setText(currCategory);

         if(prevCat.equalsIgnoreCase(currCategory)){


             holder.categBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


         }else{

                    holder.categBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         }

         prevCat= currCategory;

         OnClickListener mOnImagebtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final int position = ProductsActivity.listView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
                    Log.v(TAG, "Image button in list clicked, row ="+position);

                    ListAdapter la=     ProductsActivity.listView.getAdapter();
                       System.out.println("list adapter from get is ="+la);

                    int cnt =     getPositionFromRowId(la, position, 0, la.getCount());

                     System.out.println("info from new mthod ="+cnt);

                }
            };

            holder.imgBtnLv.setOnClickListener(mOnImagebtnClickListener);

            view.setTag(holder);


    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvCode;
        TextView tvItemName,tvItemType,tvPrice,tvQuantity;
         RelativeLayout item_detail_layout;
         ImageButton imgBtnLv;
         LinearLayout categBar;
         TextView tvTitleCateg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using ViewHolder makes no sense. It's useless IMHO. See here:
http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

You are not inflating any views here so you don't need it. ViewHolder should be used to remove redundant view inflating and to reuse view, but in Cursor adapter reusing view is already done. So you can delete it.

Comment: actually as i told you i am calling this constructor from one activity , in that activity i have one list view, and in this constructor i am passing one list item view there i have all these textviews and layouts. Now i am confused, is it not inflating a view?

Comment: BindView just binds data to your view, in cursorAdapter view is inflating in newView method.

Comment: but michal, its inflating the the items in a list.